# How would I read the contents of a text file and run a command for each line?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that remotely connects to machines over a vpn to download files using robocopy.
Currently it asks for domain credentials and IP address to each machine.

We have 100+ machines and its getting pretty tiresome having to type in an IP each time to run a command.

What I am trying to look for is to have a text file with an IP address on each line, and for the batch file to run its robocopy command for each of those IP addresses. The user will only need to enter their domain credentials once.

This is what I currently have:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P ipaddress= Please enter an IP address
SET /P sitenum= Please enter the store number
CLS
SET /P user= Please enter your domain username
SET /P pass= Please enteer your domain password
CLS

Set filedate=%date:/=%


NET USE \\%ipaddress%\IPC$ /u:DOMAIN\%user% %pass% 

ECHO Copying Dataset...
Robocopy "\\%ipaddress%\C$\ProgramData\App\Data" /Z /S "D:\Transfer Files\%sitenum%\%filedate%\Data" /eta
ECHO Done!

ECHO Copying ControlPoint Server Data....
Robocopy "\\%ipaddress%\C$\ProgramData\App\MoreData" /Z /S "D:\Transfer Files\%sitenum%\%filedate%\More Data" /eta
ECHO Done!

NET USE \\%ipaddress%\IPC$ /D
```

This is probably the most advanced bit of batch that I have put together using googles help!

I have looked into "/F "tokens" but then thats as far as I can figure out. I normally enjoy building these things myself, but on this one occasion I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read IPs from text file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (IPs.TXT) do (
    NET USE \\%%a\IPC$ /u:DOMAIN\%user% %pass% 
    ECHO Copying Dataset...
    Robocopy "\\%%a\C$\ProgramData\App\Data" /Z /S "D:\Transfer Files\%sitenum%\%filedate%\Data" /eta
    ECHO Done!

   ECHO Copying ControlPoint Server Data....
   Robocopy "\\%%a\C$\ProgramData\App\MoreData" /Z /S "D:\Transfer Files\%sitenum%\%filedate%\More Data" /eta
   ECHO Done!

   NET USE \\%%a\IPC$ /D
)
```

Comment: Thank you Endoro, I will give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a script once for each line in a file you can surround your script with :

```
while read data; do
    //your scipt goes here
done
```

The `$data` will contain a line from your file (so, an IP address).

Then you can use your script like that : `yourScript.sh < ipFile.txt`

Comment: You mean a Unix shell script (_bash_), I guess, the OP means _batch_ (Windows command shell script).